# difference between 'frustrating to me' and 'frustrating for me'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The need to check each new word in the dictionary has been quite
>   **frustrating to me**.
>
> The need to check each new word in the dictionary has been quite
>   **frustrating for me**.

What's the difference in meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a nuanced difference, it is that **to me** can express an opinion

> To me, it's a no-brainer: buy the car that offers the warranty.

whereas **for me** can express the idea of "having an effect upon me".

> For me, the reorganization has been quite stressful, but some of my colleagues seem carefree.

The speaker who uses **to me** seems to be expressing a point-of-view, using "frustrating" indirectly as a criticism of the situation; the speaker who uses **for me** is speaking of the effect upon them.

But there is really no way to be sure, since these prepositions can overlap.

Comment: I think that "to me" and "for me" are interchangeable in your examples."**For me**, it's a no-brainer: buy the car that offers the warranty" feels exactly the same as your sentence, to be honest.

Comment: @kandyman: It's not that the prepositions do not overlap; they do. What matters when trying to see if there is a difference is where they *diverge*.

Comment: Yes but my point is that they don't diverge in your examples (in my opinion). If you had examples where there was a clear divergence then your point would be valid.

Comment: I would not say "The reorg has been **stressful to me**". But many speakers would. It's hard to come up with an example that is clear-cut when prepositions are involved. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stressful+to+her%2Cstressful+for+her&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstressful%20to%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstressful%20for%20her%3B%2Cc0

Comment: But you are now referring to a different part of the sentence than I pointed out. I was simply saying that "**To me**, it's a no-brainer" and "**For me**, it's a no-brainer" sound exactly the same. And that the lack of divergence between them does not highlight the difference you claimed it did.

Comment: @kandyman: What I'm saying is that for me they diverge but perhaps not for you.  I wouldn't say "For me it's a no-brainer" when expressing the idea "as I see it".  But I would say "For me it is difficult".

Comment: Sorry but I still fail to see the difference between "frustrating for me" and "frustrating to me". In my opinion there isn't enough evidence to state that "frustrating to me " = expressing an opinion, but "frustrating for me" = expressing effects on someone. But let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @kandyman: It's not a matter of disagreeing or agreeing.  As many (not all) speakers use these prepositions, **to me** means "as I see it" and **for me** means "as it affects me, as far as it concerns me".   If you do not admit a difference between those two paraphrases, then so be it.

Comment: "frustrating to me" is clearly intended to express a feeling of frustration on the part of the speaker. It is an expression of feeling, not some kind of dissociated opinion in which "as I see it" would be more appropriate. "frustrating to me" is an overt expression of how the situation is affecting the speaker. That is why I do not agree with your analysis.

Comment: @kandyman: "clearly" to you perhaps.Since I and many other speakers would not normally say *frustrating **to** me* just as we would not say *stressful **to** me*, if we were to say it, it would not be in reference to our feeling of frustration but  to the conditions that cause that feeling.

Comment: Clearly we disagree.

Comment: No, we don't disagree since you're not even addressing the point I've made about how not all speakers use these prepositions in the same way, and how these phrases could mean different things to different speakers. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stressful+to+her%2Cstressful+for+her%2Cfrustrating+to+her%2Cfrustrating+for+her&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstressful%20to%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstressful%20for%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrustrating%20to%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrustrating%20for%20her%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Descriptive statistics like the ngram data you cited are not proof of the 'correctness' of one construction over another. They are a merely a description of what is being used more often at a given time. That does not constitute evidence that one is correct and the other is incorrect. I disagree with your analysis and I have already clearly stated my reasons for doing so. If that is frustrating to you, I'm afraid I cannot help. It is not my intention to argue back and forth with you, and as you seem to insist on having the final word anyway, go ahead.

Comment: @kandyman:  I'm not talking about "correctness" at all but about how these prepositions are used differently by different people, such that for one group "to me" and "for me" could express a nuanced difference, though not necessarily for all speakers.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this example.May be find out the difference.

**frustrating for me**

1. It's really frustrating for me.
2. "It was frustrating for me, I can't lie," Davis said.

**frustrating to me**

1. That attitude, he said, was "frustrating to me as the financial person".
2. It was frustrating to me not to be able to make a difference.

Comment: So "for me" is more like you are experiencing it, while "to me" is more like you are passing your judgment on it and are not necessarily experiencing it, right?

Comment: you got the point.

Comment: To me it sounds natural to swap "to" with "for", or vice-versa, in all of your examples, e.g. *"It's really frustrating **to** me"*, *"It was frustrating **for** me as the financial person"*.  In any case, you haven't provided any explanation of the difference (if any), just some idiomatic examples.  I can't upvote an answer that is incomplete and possibly incorrect.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew - "to me" and "for me" feel interchangeable in all four sentences in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When do you say something is frustrating "to" you? when you already experienced something, right? In my opinion, "to" and "for" both sound fine.